# Emotional Release: Images Versus Dry Body Awareness

Tags: meditation

I am posting because I have had for the past years, despite my attempts at resolving this, trouble feeling my emotions and sensations. You could almost say I'm numb. To remedy this problem, I've thought of engaging in two practices.

First, I thought of sensing the basic aspects of the body, in my whole body, e.g. tingling, warmth/cold, numbness, etc. This has not let to gains so far because I seemingly cannot engage in discursive or associative thought while doing this, so I just feel my sensations mindfully period.

Second, I thought of visualizing images that I free-associate with, and in this situation lust in the form of images, anger in the form of images, and memories in the form of images arise. However, I'm worried that this might involve elaboration that doesn't exist, i.e. fantasy elements. However, if this is not undoing repression, I am not sure how else to undo my emotional repression.

Any thoughts would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lack of sensitivity can occur due to using meditation techniques. Whenever a technique is used, such as watching breathing at abdomen or nose-tip, body scanning or the two methods proposed in the question, there will be a deliberate, fixed & gross intention operating in the mind to exert the mind. This 'intention'  & 'exertion' is a thought and it is this thought intention that hinders sensitivity.

To feel the body, breathing & associated feelings & emotions sensitively, the ideal practise is to simply 'let go' of all wanting & all intention. The mind must be quiet however the effort used must be a little as possible. Just sit, but very quietly.

Answer (score 0):

Your metal experiences (thoughts, memories, emotions, etc) create sensations. You should use it to reduce your unwholesome roots. Even visualisation is a function of the mind.

> ...
>
> **Latent tendencies**
>
> *LATENT TENDENCIES ARISING THROUGH THE MIND.* Bhikshus, dependent on mind and mind-objects, eye-consciousness arises.
>
> When the three meet, there is contact. Dependent on contact, there is what is
>   felt as ***pleasant***, or as ***painful***, or as ***neither pleasant nor painful***.
>
> When one is touched by a ***pleasant*** feeling, *one delights in it, welcomes it, remains attached to it. Thus one’s latent tendency of **lust** (rāgânusaya)
>   lies latent.*
>
> When one is touched by a ***painful*** feeling, *one sorrows, grieves, laments, beats one’s breast and falls into confusion. Thus one’s latent tendency of **aversion** (paṭighânusaya) lies latent.*
>
> When one is touched by a feeling that is ***neither pleasant nor painful***, *one does not understand it as it really is, the arising, the passing away, the gratification, the danger, and the escape with regards to that feeling. Thus one’s latent tendency of **ignorance** (avijjā’nusaya) lies latent.*
>
> Bhikshus, that one could make an end of suffering here and now, ***without* abandoning *lust* for *pleasurable* feelings, *without* removing *aversion* towards *painful* feelings,
>   *without* uprooting *ignorance* towards feelings that are *neither pleasant nor painful* this is *impossible***.
>
> ...
>
> **Abandoning the latent tendencies**
>
> *ABANDONING LATENT TENDENCIES ARISING THROUGH THE MIND.*
>
> ...
>
> Bhikshus, that one could make an end of suffering here and now,
>   ***having* abandoned *lust* for *pleasurable* feelings,
>   *having* removed *aversion* towards *painful* feelings,
>   *having* uprooted *ignorance* towards feelings that are *neither pleasant nor painful* this is *possible***.
>
> ...

[Cha Chakka Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/26.6-Chachakka-S-m148-piya.pdf)

When you are mindful about the body you experience the [Mahābhūta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mah%C4%81bh%C5%ABta) through these have an impact on if it is pleasurable or not. [Dhātu Vibhaṅga Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/4.17-Dhatu-Vibhanga-S-m140-piya.pdf), [Titth’ayatana Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/6.8-Titthayatana-S-a03.61-piya.pdf) and other similar suttas analyse this aspect in the section about the 6 elements (bodily aspect) as well as the mental aspect under the section on 18 mental examination (metal aspect - including visualisation).

Answer (score 0):

According to the Law of Action and Reaction ,**Every action of the Individual will be Neutralized by a Reaction from Nature**. *If you want Body Consciousness ,then you must think of Universal Consciousness*. 
If you are concentrating or observing or being conscious  of your Breathing Process (*Pranayama*) ,then ***think*** that the **Air that you Breathe ,fills the Universe and Infinite Space as Ether** . The Air becomes less and less dense ,as we move away from the Earth ,but it never-the-less exists as Ether (*Sunya or Brahma* ) .
 This thought will create an Universal Consciousness . **Body Consciousness will come as a Reaction to this thought** . 
 An alternative , is to study some popular books on  Cosmology.