# How to do an intense home retreat?

Tags: personal-practice, retreat

I am planning to do an intense home retreat, of 2-3 months -- just like a ven. Mahasi Sayadaw retreat: which means 1 hour walking, 1 hour sitting, all day long, short sleep, repeat.

The thing is, to do a long intense retreat in this tradition (ven. Ajhan Tong Sirimangalo technique, to be specific), I think you need a teacher.

Is there a way I can do a retreat alone at home, with some other technique maybe?

I would like as much advice from as much people here -- in case they know of ways to do a home-alone *intense* retreat -- without a teacher.

Comment: Do you need to do this with other people?
Or
Do you need to do this solitary?

Comment: Im doing it alone at home - though if i get someone to guide me it can be better i think  - and if i find a teacher to guide me than that would be better

Comment: similar: https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/18209/any-tips-on-creating-a-stay-at-home-retreat/18212#18212

Comment: thank you -  i did saw that and thats why i emphesized in this question that its an intense home retreat in difference to what seems that people answered that question

Answer (score 1):

The Buddha, according to tradition, sat under the bodhi tree for 7 days without moving. Source:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodhi_Tree.
He had practiced with other teachers before this though.

Answer (score 0):

Live in the present moment as long as possible. That is the way. Don't bear the future burden. Like driving a vehicle. Cut down thinking. Study following links well before start.
http://www.nissarana.lk/audio-and-publications/publications-english/
http://www.nissarana.lk/file_manager/browseCollections.php?CGroup=2
wwwDOTyoutubeDOTcom/watch?v=LEIUpGmmEGQ