# Advices on start practicing

Tags: beginner

I've read an introductory book written by Hsing Yun, about humanistic budhism.

I meditate every day, and now I feel like taking the next step in my journey. I don't know people who practice budhism, and I have many doubts... There is a temple near my city, but I feel a little intimidate by the number of tourists that shows up there, and the only practices that I know of, are paid meditation courses.

How do I start practicing with more people? And who do I look for when I have doubts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Courses conducted by

- http://dhamma.org/
- http://www.internationalmeditationcentre.org/

Are done solely on donation basis without commercial interest. It is best to take such a course as there will be lesser distraction including people.

There are multiple centres worldwide and has the best out reach. Also you can watch some [testimonials](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=vipassana+meditation+testimonial) and [experiences](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=vipassana%20meditation%20experience) to build some confidence in the technique.

In addition you can try to find a teacher and course through:

- http://www.buddhanet.info/wbd/

And also online material on meditation.

But in doing so be careful. Even choosing any online guided meditation instruction see if it adheres to the following principles: Any [sensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedan%C4%81) is [unsatisfactory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dukkha) this is the link to understand the [4 Noble Truths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Noble_Truths) and also with sensation, according to [dependent origination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prat%C4%ABtyasamutp%C4%81da), arises [craving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ta%E1%B9%87h%C4%81) which fuels the vicious cycle which keeps you in misery. If this is missing, you will miss the path and benefits of meditation. Also make sure any instruction in these online retreats are not contrary or tangential to the right view as mentioned in the [Samma Ditthi Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/11.14-Samma-Ditthi-S-m9-piya.pdf).

In addition you can try building you knowledge further. Some resources website:

- http://dharmafarer.org/
- http://www.vridhamma.org/Research-Index
- http://www.vridhamma.org/Research
- http://www.vridhamma.org/Online-Books-and-Pamphlets
- http://www.dhammasukha.org/
- http://www.dhammatalks.org/
- http://www.dhammatalks.net/
- http://www.ahandfulofleaves.org/Library.html
- http://www.accesstoinsight.org/
- http://www.abhidhamma.com/
- https://suttacentral.net/

Also another beginner to intermediate book that might be of help to further your knowledge might be: [In the Buddha's Words: An Anthology of Discourses from the Pali Canon](http://www.pacificbuddha.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/In-the-Buddhas-Words.pdf) edited by Bhikkhu Bodhi

Answer (score 1):

Read the 2 booklets "How to Meditate" part 1 & part 2 found [here.](http://www.sirimangalo.org/text/)
Then signup for a free online meditation course at https://meditation.sirimangalo.org/schedule.
This course is conducted by [venerable Yuttadhammo](https://www.youtube.com/user/yuttadhammo) who instructs both novice and advanced meditators

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Lede Sayardaw practice taught by Sayargyi U Ba Khin and also Mahasi Sayardaw Books for detail reading. But basic technique should be focused on only one. "Breathe in, know it, breathe out, know it" focusing on tip of the nose. It is the simplest one and easiest way to follow. One may think it is the beginning of the practice, but in fact it is the beginning, middle and the final goal to enlightenment. Mahasi Sayardaw technique on noting arising and falling abdomen is if not practiced and have experience first is kind of difficult to follow but once used to it, is also very simple and also lead to the goal. But just take only one otherwise confusing to get progress although it is the very first step. But Mahasi sayardaw books are so convincing and detailed that they are just exactly like  meditation master guiding closely to you. 
Once you get the basic, no need for the retreat. Just continue to practice. The most important thing is one's strong belief in Dhamma and in the meditation master. And one must do practice insight meditation for fear of consequence of Sansara. Only after that one will get enlightened in seven days to seven years as Buddha said. Otherwise just to accumulate merit for the afterlife still it is worth doing.  But to get enlightened in this very life must be the target.